Microcontrolador
Tengo una duda, mi programa se basa en un PIC16F628A con un MPLAB v3.26 donde debo hacer rotar un motor de un sentido a otro, mientras hace esto se debe mostrar su sentido de rotacion en un display LCD, esto a base del uso de interrupciones.
Ahora bien, esto esta hecho pero pareciera que no ejecuta esto correctamente, es decir, cada 300ms deberia ejecutar el cambio de sentido en la interrupcion y ahi recien cambiar el cartel, pero este lo hace constantemente y ademas nunca gira a la izquierda.
No esta funcionando bien y ya no se que cosas tocar.
; TODO INSERT CONFIG CODE HERE USING CONFIG BITS GENERATOR
#include "p16f628a.inc"
; CONFIG
; __config 0x3FFC
 __CONFIG _FOSC_INTOSCIO & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _MCLRE_ON & _BOREN_ON & _LVP_ON & _CPD_OFF & _CP_OFF

    org     0x00            ; Aqui comienza el micro.-
    goto    Inicio          ; Salto a inicio de mi programa.-
    
;**** Vector de Interrupcion ****
    org     0x04            ; Atiendo Interrupcion.-
    goto    ISR

; Defino los cuatro comandos que debo mandarle al LCD para que funcione como yo quiero.
func     equ h'38'      ; interfaz ocho bits y dos renglones.
clear    equ h'01'  ; Comando para limpiar el display.
home     equ h'03'  ; Posiciona el cursor al inicio.
cursor   equ h'0f'  ; Tipo de cursor parpadeante.
renglon1 equ h'80'  ; Inicio de RAM interna renglon1.

 ;***** Defino contadores para demoras y algon buffer auxiliar ************
J   equ h'20'
K   equ h'21'

;***** Defino las variables de control del motor ************
INDEX   equ h'22'
SENTIDO_GIRO_ACTUAL equ h'23'       ; bit 0: 0 derecha | 1 izquierda.
ESTADO_MOTOR        equ h'24'       ; bit 0: 0 apagado | 1 encendido.
DIO_UNA_VUELTA      equ h'25'       ; bit 0: 0 no dio una vuelta 
                    ;        1 si dio una vuelta.
                    
;*****  Configuracion Inicial del programa ************
    org     0x05            ; Origen del programa.

Inicio
    movlw h'07'
    movwf CMCON

 ;-------- Asignando LCD y motor ----------;
    bsf STATUS, RP0
    clrf VRCON
    clrf TRISB      ; escribo los comandos y datos a enviar.
    clrf TRISA      ; RA6/7 - RS y E | El resto es del motor.
    bcf STATUS, RP0

 ;-------- Asignando interrupcion ----------;
    movlw   b'00110001'     ; Se selecciona TMR1, preescaler de 1/8, modo temporizador.
    movwf   T1CON
    call APAGAR_MOTOR       ; Empieza apagado.
    movlw   0x6D        ; Cargamos TMR1H
    movwf   TMR1H       ; Byte alto de TMR1
    movlw   0x84        ; Cargamos TMR1L
    movwf   TMR1L       ; Byte bajo de TMR1

    bsf STATUS, RP0     ; Cambia a Banco 1
    bsf PIE1, TMR1IE        ; Activa interrupcion por TMR1
    bsf INTCON, GIE     ; Habilita interrupciones globales.
    bsf INTCON, PEIE        ; Habilita interrupcion por perifericos
    bcf STATUS, RP0     ; Regresa a Banco 0
    bsf PCON, 3         ; Configuracion adicional segun tu codigo

;*****  Inicializando programa ************
Main
    btfsc ESTADO_MOTOR, 0
    call CONFIGURAR_SENTIDO
    goto Main

;*****  Subrutinas ************
;*****  Subrutinas - MOTOR PASO A PASO ************
APAGAR_MOTOR
    clrf PORTA
    bcf DIO_UNA_VUELTA, 0
    bcf SENTIDO_GIRO_ACTUAL, 0
    bcf ESTADO_MOTOR, 0     ; NO OLVIDAR cambiar a apagado y que cambie por la interrupcion.
    clrf INDEX
   return
    
CONFIGURAR_SENTIDO
    call CONFIG_LCD
    btfss SENTIDO_GIRO_ACTUAL, 0    ; Muestra derecha.
    call CAMBIAR_DERECHA
    btfsc SENTIDO_GIRO_ACTUAL, 0    ; Muestra izquierda.
    call CAMBIAR_IZQUIERDA
;-------- Verifico el sentido de giro ----------;
    movf INDEX, 0
  ;------------------;
    btfss SENTIDO_GIRO_ACTUAL, 0
    call TABLE_RIGHT
    btfsc SENTIDO_GIRO_ACTUAL, 0
    call TABLE_LEFT
    btfsc DIO_UNA_VUELTA, 0 ; Si dio la vuelta entera, resteamos.
    call RESETEAR_CICLO
  ;------------------;
    movwf PORTA
    incf INDEX, f
    movf INDEX, 0
    return

CAMBIAR_DERECHA
    call sentidoDerecha
    return
    
CAMBIAR_IZQUIERDA
    call sentidoIzquierda
    return
    
RESETEAR_CICLO
    bcf DIO_UNA_VUELTA, 0
    clrf INDEX
    movf INDEX
    return
    
;*****  Subrutinas - LCD ************
delay   movlw d'100'    ;50 ms
    movwf K
mallaK  movwf J
mallaJ  decfsz J,f
    goto mallaJ
    decfsz K, f
    goto mallaK
    return
    
CONFIG_LCD
  movlw func
  call enco
  movlw clear
  call enco
  movlw home
  call enco
  movlw cursor
  call enco
  return

sentidoDerecha
    movlw renglon1
    call enco
    movlw ' '
    call enda
    movlw 'D'
    call enda
    movlw 'e'
    call enda
    movlw 'r'
    call enda
    movlw 'e'
    call enda
    movlw 'c'
    call enda
    movlw 'h'
    call enda
    movlw 'a'
    call enda
    movlw ' '
    call enda
    movlw ' '
    call enda
    return
   
sentidoIzquierda
    movlw renglon1
    call enco
    movlw ' '
    call enda
    movlw 'I'
    call enda
    movlw 'z'
    call enda
    movlw 'q'
    call enda
    movlw 'u'
    call enda
    movlw 'i'
    call enda
    movlw 'e'
    call enda
    movlw 'r'
    call enda
    movlw 'd'
    call enda
    movlw 'a'
    call enda
    movlw ' '
    call enda
    movlw ' '
    call enda
    return

enco
    movwf PORTB     ;escribe comando en puertoB
    call delay      ;50 milisegundos
    movlw b'01000000'   ;RS=0, EN=1
    movwf PORTA
    call delay
    movlw h'00'     ;RS=0, EN=0
    movwf PORTA
    call delay
    movlw b'01000000'
    movwf PORTA
    call delay
    return

enda
    movwf PORTB     ;escribe dato en puertoB
    call delay      ;50 milisegundos
    movlw b'11000000'   ;RS=1, EN=1
    movwf PORTA
    call delay
    movlw b'10000000'   ;RS=1, EN=0
    movwf PORTA
    call delay
    movlw b'11000000'
    movwf PORTA
    call delay
    return
    
;**** Rutina de servicio de Interrupcion ****
;**** Interrupcion por TMR1 ****

ISR
    btfss   PIR1, TMR1IF    ; Consultamos si es por TMR1.-
    retfie                  ; No, salimos de interrupcion.-

    btfss ESTADO_MOTOR, 0   ; Si esta apagado lo prendo, sino, lo apaga.   
    goto Prender_motor

    btfsc ESTADO_MOTOR, 0
    goto Sentido_motor
    
Actualizo_TMR1          ; Actualizo TMR1 para obtener una temporizacion de 400 ms.-
    movlw   0x6D        ; Cargamos TMR1H
    movwf   TMR1H       ; Byte alto de TMR1
    movlw   0x84        ; Cargamos TMR1L
    movwf   TMR1L       ; Byte bajo de TMR1
    
    goto    Fin_ISR         ; Restauro valores.-

Prender_motor
    bsf ESTADO_MOTOR, 0
    goto Actualizo_TMR1
    
Sentido_motor
    comf SENTIDO_GIRO_ACTUAL    ; Cambia el sentido cada 400ms.
    goto Actualizo_TMR1

Fin_ISR
    bcf     PIR1, TMR1IF     ; Borro bandera de control de Interrupcion.-
    retfie                  ; Salimos de interrupcion.-

;*****  Tablas del motor ************
TABLE_RIGHT
    addwf PCL
    retlw 0x09
    retlw 0x0C
    retlw 0x06
    retlw 0x03
    retlw 0x09
    retlw 0x0C
    retlw 0x06
    retlw 0x03
    bsf DIO_UNA_VUELTA, 0
    return
    
TABLE_LEFT
    addwf PCL
    retlw 0x03
    retlw 0x06
    retlw 0x0C
    retlw 0x09
    retlw 0x03
    retlw 0x06
    retlw 0x0C
    retlw 0x09
    bsf DIO_UNA_VUELTA, 0
    return

;*****  Fin del programa ************
    end

